# Stacking Divs from Bottom to Top

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, vertical-alignment, alignment

When appending `div`s to a `div` with a fixed height, the child divs will appear from top to bottom, sticking at the top border.

```
┌─────────────────────────┐
│ Child Div 1             │
│ Child Div 2             │
│                         │
│                         │
│                         │
└─────────────────────────┘
```

I'm now trying to display them from bottom to top like this (sticking to the bottom border):

```
┌─────────────────────────┐
│                         │
│                         │
│                         │
│ Child Div 1             │
│ Child Div 2             │
└─────────────────────────┘
┌─────────────────────────┐
│                         │
│                         │
│ Child Div 1             │
│ Child Div 2             │
│ Child Div 3             │
└─────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────────────┬─┐
│ Child Div 2           │▲│
│ Child Div 3           │ │
│ Child Div 4           │ │
│ Child Div 5           │█│
│ Child Div 6           │▼│
└───────────────────────┴─┘
```

And so on... I hope you get what I mean.

Is this simply doable with CSS (something like `vertical-align: bottom`)? Or do I have to hack something together with JavaScript?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

All the answers miss the **scrollbar** point of your question. And it's a tough one. If you only need this to work for modern browsers and IE 8+ you can use table positioning, `vertical-align:bottom` and `max-height`. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/display) for specific browser compatibility.

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/inuda4/6) *(vertical-align)*

```
.wrapper {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  height: 200px;
}
.content {
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

html

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
     <div>row 1</div>
     <div>row 2</div>
     <div>row 3</div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Other than that, I think it's not possible with CSS only. You can make elements stick to the bottom of their container with `position:absolute`, but it'll take them out of the flow. As a result they won't stretch and make the container to be scrollable.

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/onoqu6/8) *(position-absolute)*

```
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
}
.content {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: and `overflow-y:auto` for the container

Comment: @venimus - It would display a disabled scrollbar, because the container's height is not affected by a `position:absolute` child.

Comment: well your solution does not display any scrollbars, which is part of the question

Comment: I've updated the answer. You can work around the scrollbar issue in modern browsers (IE 7+).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the wrapper does the job well.

Answer (score 51):

**A more modern answer to this would be to use `flexbox`.**

As with many other modern features, [they won't work in legacy browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox), so unless you're ready to ditch support for browsers from the IE8-9 era you will need to look for another method.

Here's how it's done:

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.child {
  /* whatever */
}
```

And that's all you need. For further reading on `flexbox`, see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes).

Here's an example of this with some basic styling: http://codepen.io/Mest/pen/Gnbfk

Comment: Awesome answer, thank you very much! Didn't hear of flexboxes yet, sounds really interesting!

Comment: This reverses the order but doesn't pull them down to the bottom of the parent.

Comment: @nilbus would you care to elaborate? My previous tests and even the attached example most certainly seem to pull the down to the bottom of the parent element.

Comment: Seems I am mistaken. Perhaps there is a conflicting style that was keeping it from working for me. Thanks!

Comment: I found in the example code, there are .parent {position: fixed;} which makes this work. Also, the scrolling in the demo does not work on Chome, you need these: .parant {-webkit-flex: 1 1 auto; overflow-y: auto; min-height: 0px;} and remove the fixed position

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't work at all. The `column-reverse` simply reverses the order in which the children are displayed, which isn't even wanted. In the example, the children are only at the bottom because of the "basic styling" `bottom: 1em;`.

Comment: hello, you can scroll with your solution ?

Comment: @NilsKaspersson How do I reverse the order of the elements as well as align on the bottom?

Comment: for me setting the parent like :  display: flex;  flex-flow: wrap-reverse; did what I was looking for, this question was inspirational btw

Answer (score 4):

i want this work with bootstarp like chatting app where message flow bottom to up

after reading stuff , i found this

i have a outer div assume class .outerDiv
and then UI , list

```
.outerDiv {
    height: 361px;
    position: relative;
}
ui.msg-content{
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    max-height: 98%;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

We can simply use CSS transform to archive this.

I created a codepen for it.
https://codepen.io/king-dev/pen/PoPgXEg

```
.root {
  transform: scaleY(-1);
}
.root > div {
  transform: scaleY(-1);
}
```

The idea is to flip the root first vertically and then flip direct children divs again.

NOTE: the above method also reverses the order of divs.
If you simply want to place them to start from bottom you can do the following.

```
.root {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.root > div:first-child {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Keepin' it oldskool...

I wanted to do the same thing in a `#header` **div** so I created an empty **div** called `#headspace` and placed it on the top the stack (inside of `#header`):

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="headspace"></div>
    <div id="one">some content</div>
    <div id="two">other content</div>
    <div id="three">more content</div>
</div> <!-- header -->
```

Then I used a ***percentage***, for the height of the invisible `#headspace` **div**, to push the others down.  It's easy to use the developer / inspector tools of the browser to get this just right.

```
#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10rem;
    overflow: auto;
}

#headspace {
    width: 100%;
    height: 42%;    /* Experiment with Inspect (Element) tool */
}

#one, #two, #three {
    /* Insert appropriate dimensions for others... */
}
```

Comment: This will only work if you have fixed content. if you have dynamic content and don't know who many divs will be rendered, this will not work.

Comment: It was just a little solution that I'd used.  There was no specific mention of the necessity for dynamic content --for all I know the page is completely refreshed each time a `div` is appended.  So I put this here in case someone actually wants a more static solution.  In other words: I think that a *zero* vote would be more appropriate than a negative vote.

Comment: Thank you for taking time and providing an answer with static content. I respect that.
The question clearly shows dynamic content, `Child Div #` where child divs are increasing, and when increased by a certain height, there should be scroll shown. so this answer does not provide solution to actual question.

Answer (score 0):

The **`display: table-cell`** does't work if the wrapper is a flex item, possibly with fluid height (as in my case). That's why I'm in favour of the flexbox approach. Still, if you want to take the idea further, saving one line of code, you could also utilize grid and write something like this:

**CSS**

```
.big-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.wrapper {
  flex: auto;
  height: 0;
  display: grid; <!-- the important part -->
  align-content: end; <!-- the important part -->
}

.content {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="big-wrapper">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
      <div>row 1</div>
      <div>row 2</div>
      <div>row 3</div>  
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

This is simple when you use `position: absolute`.

http://jsfiddle.net/XHeZj/

Answer (score -5):

```
<div style="height: 500px;">
    <div style="height: 20px; position: absolute; bottom: 120px;">Child Div 1</div>
    <div style="height: 20px; position: absolute; bottom: 100px;">Child Div 2</div>
    <div style="height: 20px; position: absolute; bottom: 80px;">Child Div 3</div>
    <div style="height: 20px; position: absolute; bottom: 60px;">Child Div 4</div>
    <div style="height: 20px; position: absolute; bottom: 40px;">Child Div 5</div>
</div>
```