# Is it possible to position a div on top of another starting from the bottom using CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a chat window made using HTML, CSS & JS. I want to position the message from bottom to top.
Example: 
first message div at the bottom, 2nd message div on top of first an so on. Is it possible?

Comment: yea it is, but could you please update it on js fiddle or tell me what did you try?

Comment: I know a way - with only css - but it seems to me there must be a better way. I will do a fiddle and post it here. give me a couple of minutes.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6401869/stacking-divs-from-bottom-to-top

Answer (score 2):

I can't imagine a pure CSS solution. But Using jQuery, if you already have this library for your project, you could write something this:

```
$(':button').click(function() {
   var message = $('input[type=text]').val();
    $('#chat').prepend('<div class="line">'+message);
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/Vbd67/1/

**I changed the `append` to `prepend` according to the comment

Comment: your messages are from top down. the question was for bottom up.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

---

I know that this is not an answer to your question, rather this is a better option that you should consider implementing in the chat window.

**Newest comment should be at the bottom, that is how most basic chat windows work.**

Next thing, you can do this all using css:
**because such a design requires either use of table rows or list elements**
Obviously you have to use javascript for using ajax, so that you can asynchronously fetch user records like messages and profile pic etc

---

**CSS:**

```
<style type="text/css">
table#chat_window {
}
tr#message_row {
}
td#profile_pic {
}
td#message {
}
</style>
```

**HTML STRUCTURE:**

```
<table id="chat_window">
  <tr id="message_row">
    <td id="profile_pic"></td>
    <td id="message"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**OR USING LISTS:**

```
<ul id="chat_window">
  <li id="message_row">
    <div id="profile_pic"></div>
    <div id="message"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

Now you have to just using javascript:ajax to fetch values and add a child:

1. If you are using table based chat-window, then you have to fetch the table id using javascript and add row element `<tr>` per value/message that you fetch.
2. If you are using list based chat-window, then you have to fetch the list id using javascript and add list element `<li>` per value/message that you fetch.

   ---

I am sorry if there are any typos I have less time.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using jQuery like;

```
var first = $('div > div:first-child');
first.appendTo(first.parent());
```

To deal with several elements, you can do this:

```
$('div > div').each(function() {
    $(this).prependTo(this.parentNode);
});
```

***[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/SLPaY/1/)*** is a working Live Demo.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a combination of `display:table-cell` and `vertical-align:bottom`. 
I use Sotiris's fiddle and fixed its CSS.

The HTML is

```
<div  style="display:table; height:200px;">
    <div style="display:table-row">
            <div id="chat" style="width:400px; border:1px solid black;display:table-cell; vertical-align:bottom">
            </div>
    </div>

</div>
<input type="text"><input type="button" value="post">
​
```

And this is the JavaScript code

```
$(':button').click(function() {
   var message = $('input[type=text]').val();
    $('#chat').append( $('<div/>').text(message) );
});
​
```

Please let me know if there is a problem.

This is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fBCHQ/2)

I kept searching for a better solution because table layout is always suspicious to me, but I found [css-tricks article](http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/) about it and they do the same as I do.. so I guess this solution is the right one.

ADDING - keep scroll to bottom code

Since new messages are coming at the bottom, we need to keep scroll to bottom. 
I updated the fiddle link