# Stack divs from bottom to top

Tags: css, html

I'm creating a chat application and need to align messages from users the way is done in Skype, from bottom to top.

A solution was found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6401869/stacking-divs-from-bottom-to-top), 
but it has couple of flaws.

1. the height of container is a fixed height, I need to cover all available height of the window (if I use height: 100%, it shrinks completely).
2. The height of the message item is fixed, I need it to adjust to its content height.

Having a poor experience with CSS I'm having troubles to fix these 2 issues. 
Can someone point to a solution?

Comment: Both limitations are not fundamental in this method. See JSbin without these limitations: http://jsbin.com/ukumer/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

It could be easier if you have provided your own jsfiddle. But anyway, I'm trying to answer your question by taking @IlyaStreltsyn jsbin.

You can position to be fixed and set vertical-align bottom and apply the gap from bottom. Here I have used 0px for demonstration.

```
.wrapper {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 300px;
}
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/peGLj/)

Comment: If any problem, please ask your question.