# CSS: How to fill the contents of a div from the bottom / stack elements at bottom of a div

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I'm certain this will have been asked before, I just can't seem to find the right explanation to find it! [Closest question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6401869/3436942) but couldn't get those options to work for me.

I have a thin div element which will have dynamic values entered, which should 'push up' the current elements in the div higher up the div.

Currently I have looked for several related questions however these suggest positioning (`absolute/relative/etc`) however in this situation I can't work out how to implement these.

With the current markup I don't wish to use `float` as this completely mucks up the DOM and layering (which don't get me started is just not where I want to go with this).

```css
.ratingList {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 35px;
  right: 5px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 40px;
  background: red;
  text-align: center;
}

.ratingList b {
  width: 40px;
  display: block;
  height: 40px;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #333;
  line-height: 36px;
  color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="ratingList">
  ROI
  <b>12A</b> UK
  <b>15</b>
</div>
```

In essence, if I were to add another `US <b>12</b>` this should push up the current markup and appear below `UK <b>15</b>`

As this stack won't just be text (may include images), not too such if vertical-align would work.

````
```         *********
```         *       *   <-- old elements get pushed upwards (but still aligned to bottom)
```         *       *
```         *   /\  *
```         *   ||  *  
```         *       *
```         *       *   <-- child elements are aligned to the bottom of parent
```         *       *
```  new element enters here
````

Comment: a flexbox column with a flex-end alignment?

Comment: Was really trying to stay away from flexbox and floats. But that might be the only option here

Comment: what the issue with flexbox?

Comment: It was always my understanding it was quite buggy. But I suppose that was only when misused. Can flexbox be used with absolute positioning?

Comment: flexbox and abslute positioning aren't related, you can combine both like you want with no issue

Comment: I thought editing display property would've affected other CSS on the page but seems to 'not break'. Just seems a `'doh!'` moment. `Stupid question ^^`

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox makes this pretty painless - some more descriptive HTML/CSS also wouldn't go amiss, I think:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

.ratingList {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 35px;
  right: 5px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 40px;
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.tag {
  text-align: center;
}

.rating {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #333;
  line-height: 36px;
  color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="ratingList">
  <div class="tag">
    <p>ROI</p>
    <p class="rating">
      <b>12A</b>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="tag">
    <p>UK</p>
    <p class="rating">
      <b>15</b>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```